# Angular 2 : Validators.pattern() not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to validate input `type="text"` using a pattern. I want text only.

Component :

```
 this.from = this.fb.group({
  name: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/')]],

});
```

Html :

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name"/> // omitting other html template like from tag.
```

The above pattern validation is not working for me. It always returns an invalid state.

Comment: What happens if you really pass a regexp, rather than a string: `pattern(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)`?

Comment: Either that or `Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$')`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Pass pattern as string, without `/` which are the delimiters for regex

```
Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$')
```

Comment: 'pin_code': ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{1,6}$')
      ]],

Comment: REGEXP is not working is above example of my angular 4 project...just required is working from givin conditions

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Any idea why `formControl.hasError('pattern')` is giving false even though I have defined it?

Comment: @Krishna perhaps better to create a new question with a StackBlitz example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Issue is it somehow works on stackblitz but not vscode.
`this.formControl = new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.bind(this.validateIds),
      Validators.pattern(/ somepatter''/) ]);`

`console.log(this.formControl.errors)` gives only {required: true}

Answer (score 43):

Remember to not do this:

```
Validators.pattern("[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Z]?\s?[0-9][A-Z]{2}")
```

The gotcha is that you need a double backslash before the s to defeat string escape thus:

```
Validators.pattern("[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Z]?\\s?[0-9][A-Z]{2}")
```

Comment: how on earth did you know that? so only space should be double escaped? Not dot, commas?

Comment: What's happening is that you've got two layers of escaping, one in Javascript strings, and another in regular expressions. The problem is with the Javascript escaping where \ precedes a special character in a string: you avoid this by telling the JS string you actually want a backslash character by using \\. This then gets passed down to the regular expression properly.

Answer (score 33):

I had this same problem with a different pattern:

```
^\d{1,4}$
```

And I was using it like this:

```js
Validators.pattern("^\d{1,4}$") // wrong
```

The problem is that the backslash `\` has to be escaped, so the correct form is:

```js
Validators.pattern("^\\d{1,4}$") // correct
```

Answer (score 18):

```
emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
this.form = fb.group({
      Email : new FormControl({value: null}, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(this.emailRegex)]))
});
```

Comment: Good answer, although it should be updated to allow for [longer domain suffixes](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt)

Comment: Just a side note here: for validating email addresses, just use the [built-in](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#email) `Validators.email` instead of your own regexp. But in terms of illustrating that regexp literals (or variable references to them) can be passed, this answer is correct.

Answer (score 16):

This is what I've found when using `Validators.pattern()`:

**Works**

```
Validators.pattern('[a-z]{2}')
Validators.pattern(/^[a-z]{2}$/)
```

**Doesn't work**

```
Validators.pattern(/[a-z]{2}/i)
Validators.pattern(/[a-z]{2}/)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the validator as string or regex, both work if you do it correctly.
Let's consider the requirement *text only*:

**As regex**

```
const regex = /[a-zA-Z]*/;
let formControl = new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(regex));
```

In a `FormControl`, the validator will set state `VALID` if any matches to the regex are found (substrings). Therefore we need to specify the beginning and end of the input to enforce exact matches, by `^` and `$`:

```
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
```

This will return `VALID` for single words, which satisfies the OPs requirement. However, it will return `INVALID` for longer text containing whitespace, commas, punctuations and hyphens. So if we want, we can add those to the character set:

```
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z,.\s-]*$/;
```

Since we are working with a regex, we can simplify the character set by setting the `i` flag at the end. This tells the regex to ignore case-sensitivity, so it's enough with only one of the character ranges:

```
const regex = /^[a-z,.\s-]*$/i;
```

The above regex will be `VALID` for any text containing UPPER-CASE, lower-case, whitespaces, punctuation and commas. If you want to accept exclamation marks and questions marks as well, simply add them to the character set:

```
const regex = /^[a-z,.!?\s-]*$/i;
```

**As string**

When passing the validator expression as a string, you do not use the regex delimiters `/ /`, and cannot pass regex flags. As a consequence, we have to include both UPPER and lower case characters in the set. As others point out, you also have to escape any backward slashes in a string.

The equivalent validator as a string would look like this:

```
const validatorString = '^[a-zA-Z,.!?\\s-]*$';
let formControl = new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(validatorString));
```

Note that if you leave out the `^` and `$` when the expression is passed as a string, Angular will automatically add them when processing the validator. That's why passing the expression as a string often appears to work better than regex. Personally, I prefer regex over string.

To better understand the concepts of Regular Expressions, I highly recommend this website:
https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Text + 'space'

```
Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*')
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried using the `Validators.pattern` with a regex string like this

```
Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]{6}') // Didn't work
```

But when I was reading the docs, I've noticed that **If a string is passed, the `^` character is prepended and the `&` character is appended to the provided string (if not already present)**

[image]

This is what worked for me

```
Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z]{6}$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need string in Validator.pattern. You can either use string or regex expression directly. See:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem converting from c# to angular.
You need an extra backslash on the \d but not on the regular escaped characters.

```
ValidationExpression="[\d|\*|w|#]{0,25}"

to

Validators.pattern('[\\d|*|w|#]{0,25}')
```