# How to fix ' Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | RegExp' '

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I am trying to prevent the user from using any special symbols and also from having blank spaces without a character.  When I try to put it on my FormGroup Validator I get an error saying 'Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | RegExp''

```
this.houseForm = this.fb.group({
      address: [
        null,         
        [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*)],
      ]
    });
```

Comment: `Validators.pattern(/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/)`?

Comment: That's the regex part, but I get an error saying 'Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | RegExp''

Comment: Try passing as a string - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392373/angular-2-validators-pattern-not-working

Comment: @Vandesh It is the same. `Validators.pattern` accepts both. `Validators.pattern(/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/)` = `Validators.pattern("[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*")`

Comment: To clarify, the detail being pointed out is that your pattern is not enclosed within slashes (i.e. `/`, which is the syntax for instantiating a `RegExp` object), nor is it enclosed within quotes (which would make it a string literal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Validators.pattern()` is expecting either a string or a regex.  You are providing neither.

You have provided `^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*`, but what you need is either:

`/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*/` or

`'^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 ]*'`

Need to surround it with slash `/` for Regex or quote `'` for string.

https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern