# Validation text field in Mobile Browser not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

- Text box validation in mobile browser not working for my Angular application
- **Mobile Browser:** Chrome , Samsung Browser (not working in both browser)
- **Expected** **0 to 9** and **A to Z only** in Text field

I used :

**1. Firstly** I tried to validate it by using charCode of key , for Laptop 
    browser it worked but for Mobile browser It did not worked .

> phone browser character code was 229 for every key , so it did not 
>   worked

**Code**

HTML

```
<input (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" type="text" />
```

TS

```
numberOnly(event): boolean {
    const charCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

**2. Secondly** I created a directive and with the help of directive I tried to validate , **which again did not worked for me in mobile browser** , In Laptop browser it was working.

Directive code :

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[specialIsAlphaNumeric]'
})
export class SpecialCharacterDirective {

  regexStr = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$';
  @Input() isAlphaNumeric: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    return new RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) blockPaste(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.validateFields(event);
  }

  validateFields(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {

      this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
      event.preventDefault();

    }, 100)
  }

}
```

**3. third** I used pattern , **but again it was not working in mobile browser** , in laptop browser it was working

**Pattern I used  :** /[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}/i
I created a reactive form and then I validated using Validator.pattern

```
username: ['', Validators.pattern('/[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}/i')],})
```

HTML

```
<input  formcontrolname='username' (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" type="text" />
```

Playground : 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-hellman-pygp1?file=/src/app/app.component.html:64-119&codemirror=1

Comment: `Validators.pattern('/[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}/i')` should be written as `Validators.pattern(/^[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]$/i)` if your intention is to match strings that start with 5 letters, then have 4 digits and then a single letter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  It did not worked in mobile browser

Comment: That just means your code is wrong, the regex is correct.

Comment: I think solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392373/angular-2-validators-pattern-not-working Pass pattern as string, without / which are the delimiters for regex

Answer (score 0):

I read here that you should make sure that JS is enabled in the browser that you are using.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e62fa103-1afc-4066-9107-ae2117da3a6b/client-side-validation-not-working-on-mobile-devices?forum=aspmobileandhandheld

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33139860)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure JavaScript is enabled in the mobile browser settings!

reference:
[Client side validation not working on mobile devices](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e62fa103-1afc-4066-9107-ae2117da3a6b/client-side-validation-not-working-on-mobile-devices?forum=aspmobileandhandheld)

Comment: That's exactly what the other answer says, isn't it?